# error mssage Object required in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery

i am working on an application where i get some data from the database via jquery ajax and display append it a table.this app works very well with firefox and chrome but when tasted  with internet explorer i get the error OBJECT Required code 0 the issue i really donot know what the problem is or how to go abot it .i am using ie6. thanks in adavance

```
var ename =$(this).find('ENAME').text();
var pnr =$(this).find('PNR').text();
var inr =$(this).find('INR').text();
var operator =$(this).find('OPERATOR').text();
var maxstime =$(this).find('MAXSTIME').text();
var timeagg =$(this).find('TIMEAGG').text();
var link =$('<a class=\"item\" href=\"#\">'+ename+'</a>');
var new_tr=$('<tr></tr>');
if(index%2==1){new_tr.css({backgroundColor:'#7cb6f2'});}
var new_td_1=$('<td></td>').append(link);
    new_tr.append(new_td_1);
var new_td_2=$('<td></td>').text(operator);
    new_tr.append(new_td_2);
var new_td_3=$('<td></td>').text(pnr);
    new_tr.append(new_td_3);
var new_td_4=$('<td></td>').text(inr);
    new_tr.append(new_td_4);
var new_td_5=$('<td></td>').text(maxstime);
    new_tr.append(new_td_5);
var new_td_6=$('<td></td>').text(timeagg);
    new_tr.append(new_td_6);

$('table tbody').append(new_tr);
$('#mytable').tablesorter();` <table id="mytable" border="1px" width="100%">
         <thead>
             <tr>  
                  <th>NAME</th>
                  <th>OPERATOR</th>
                  <th>PNR</th>
                  <th>INR</th>
                  <th>MAXSTIME</th>
                  <th>TIMEAGG</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         </tbody>
      </table>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would suggest, if at all possible, upgrade to IE8 so you can use the developer tools to step through you code and find out where the error is.